# how can I implement RunTimePermissions for android m device in an android service

Tags: android, android-service, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

how can i implement RunTimePermissions for android m device in an android service like i implement audio recording service but in android m device crashed while i add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

in androidManifest.xml but again when i debug I permission denied error come how can i implement in this service. while i know its easy to implement this RunTimePermissions in android activity how can i implement permission dialog in a service

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to have your service see if it has permission (e.g., via `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()`).

However, to *request* a permission, you *must* do that from an activity (e.g., via `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`).

If your service determines that it does not have permission to do the work, raise a `Notification` to that effect, where you lead the user into an activity where you request the permission.